# how to pass vector dataframe and loop in a function python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to call a functiopn that loops in a dataframe and call different functions based on if the dataframe column name is in another dataframe. But i cannot find the most efficient and fast way of doing it.
I tried passing in a vectorized way but this doesnt seem to work. Also i need a way to do it faster because the original dataframe is like with 10k names in it. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
def multiply(value, date, df1, df2):
   if value in df1['name'].values:
      value_ = value * 2
   elif value in df2['name'].values:
       value_ = value * 3
   return value_

df=pd.DataFrame({"name": ['joe','jack'], "date":[30,20]})

df1=pd.DataFrame({"name": ['joe','ben'], "date":[10,70]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"name": ['ian','jack'], "date":[10,20]})

df['returned'] = multiply(df['name'].values, df['date'].values, df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`np.select`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) like:

```
conditions = [df['name'].isin(df1['name']), df['name'].isin(df2['name'])]
choices = [df1['date']*2, df2['date']*3]
df['returned'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
print (df)
   name  date  returned
0   joe    30        20
1  jack    20        60
```